# Sending all regex matches as arguments

Tags: ruby

I have a "table" of substitution rules stored in a hash, where each key is the rule and each value is a method that will take matched text and send those as arguments. Each method will return a string. Except I don't know how to send all matches. How can I fill in the comment in the `send` call to accomplish this?

```
Sub_Rules = {
   /N\[(\d+)\]/i          => :do_something,
   /N\[(\d+)\]\[(\d+)\]/i => :do_something_else
}

def do_something(*args)
  "something based on the args"
end

def do_something_else(*args)
  "something else based on the args"
end

text = "N[2]"
Sub_Rules.each {|rule, method|
  p text.gsub(rule) {send(method, #the matches?)}
}
```

If I wanted to hardcode it, I might do something like this:

```
text.gsub(/N\[(\d+)\]/i) { do_something($1) }
```

Comment: Does your "I might do something like this" code do what you want? If not, why doesn't it?

Comment: It works but I don't want to hardcode it. I want to loop the rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `text.gsub(/N\[(\d+)\]/i) { do_something($1) }` works, then this will too:

```
Sub_Rules.each do |rule, method|
  p text.gsub(rule) { send(method, $1) }
end
```

But I suspect that `text.gsub(/N\[(\d+)\]/i) { do_something($1) }` doesn't actually work seeing as it doesn't "send all matches" either. Instead you probably want

```
Sub_Rules.each do |rule, method|
  p text.gsub(rule) { send(method, $~.captures) }
end
```

which will send an array of the [captures](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/MatchData.html#method-i-captures) from each group in the regex.

Comment: Oh you were referring to whether `$1` sent everything. Lol yes it only sent the first match but the `$~.captures` is what I was looking for.